# Using multiple classes in a form_for Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, class

I'm trying to create a form_for using the following fields. However, some of the fields correspond to one model, the RecipeIngredient class (model), whereas the bottom fields correspond to the Recipe class (model).

```
  <%= form_for(:recipe_and_ingredients, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

<!-- RecipeIngredient classs -->
<table>
<tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td><%= f.text_field(:quantity) %></td>
 <td><%= f.text_field(:weight) %></td>
 <td><%= f.text_field(:units) %></td>
</tr>
</table> 


<!-- Recipe class -->
<table summary="Recipe form fields">
  <tr>
    <th>Recipe Name</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:recipe_name) %></td>
    <th>Total Grams</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:total_grams) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-buttons">
  <%= submit_tag("Create Recipe") %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

However, in my controller:

```
 # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe_and_ingredients])
  @ingredient = RecipeIngredient.new(params[:recipe_and_ingredients])
```

I get this error when I submit the form

```
  unknown attribute: quantity
```

I know this is because the Recipe model/class/table/whatever does not have a quantity column; that is a column within RecipeIngredient (which is supposed to be a join table between Recipe and some other table if that is relevant). When I submit the params however, how do I differentiate, in the code, which parameters belong to which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use
In the model:   `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
In the controller: Nothing
In the routes: Nothing
In the view, at the point where you want the 'nested' fields, use `f.fields_for :other_model do |inner|` and then you can use `inner.inner_field_name`.  I think inner would be ingredient in your case, if that is what RecipieIngredient is and you renamed it to ingredient.  If receipieIngredient is actually a more complex join table redo as needed.

See more at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

I would name the entities 'recipies' and 'ingredients' and then have a form for a recipie that has `fields_for :ingredients do |i|`.

If you want `Ingredient has_many recipies` and `Recipie has_many ingredients`, you can do that too with `has_many_through` in both of the models pointing to a join model `IngredientRecipie` which belongs to_both recipie and ingredient but that doesn't affect the form.  Those relationships are used to retrieve data.

Note that if you have these has_many through you can use simple_form to just maintain the relationship with checkboxes for the relationships and no other code to write other than saving the data with one save.

Update:

```
Recipie (model)
Recipie has_many :recipie_ingredients
Recipie has many :ingredients, :through => :recipie_ingredients

Ingredient (model)
Recipie has_many :recipie_ingredients
Recipie has many :ingredients, :through => :recipie_ingredients

RecipieIngredient (model)
belongs_to :recipies
belongs_to :ingredients
```

Comment: I have the `recipe has_many foods` and `foods has_many recipes`, and I use a `:through` with a join table called `Recipe_Ingredients`. Should I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the Recipe model AND the Recipe_Ingredients join model, or just one of them?

Comment: I updated the answer with how it might be laid out.  For your question:- If you want to be able to add many ingredients 'at once' to a recipie then you need the `has_many`'s in `Recipie` and the first `belongs_to` in `RecipieIngredient`.  If you want to be able to add a single ingredients to a bunch of Recipies at once then you need the `has_many`'s in `Ingredients` and the second `belongs_to`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could solve this.

The first is using ActiveRecord delegation to put a child model's attribute on the parent model. You can see the documentation for how to do that here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Secondly, you can use nested forms to have a part of this form belong to a different model object. You can see the documentation on that here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: +1 for this.  Even though it's a competing answer to mine,  using delegates is a great practice.